# retrofit JSON array to recyclerview

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

i have JSON response like this

```
[{"id":94973,"slug":"la-liga-real-betis-1-1-barcelona-29-januari-2017","type":"post"},{"id":94957,"slug":"fa-chelsea-4-0-brentford-28-januari-2017","type":"post"},{"id":94944,"slug":"serie-a-ac-milan-1-2-napoli-22-januari-2017","type":"post"},{"id":94663,"slug":"boullier-soroti-performa-mclaren-musim-ini","type":"post"},{"id":94660,"slug":"balotelli-tawarkan-diri-ke-sassuolo","type":"post"}]
```

and i want to pass this with retrofit
i already check there is nothing wrong with get data from  json, but my recyclerview doesnt show any data.i think i was wrong at pass the response to the arraylist then adapter.

my on response  class

```
public class EditorFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<Coba> data;
//private List<Coba> tes;
private MyAdapter adapter;


public EditorFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadJSON();
}


private void loadJSON(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://www.opinianda.com/wp-json/wp/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestSumbol request = retrofit.create(RequestSumbol.class);
    Call<List<Coba>> call = request.getPostDet();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Coba>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Coba>> call, Response<List<Coba>> response) {
            try {
                List<Coba> jsonResponse = response.body();
                data = new ArrayList<>(jsonResponse);
                Log.i("HASIL", "onResponse: "+data);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Coba>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   // loadJSON();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

and this onbindview in my adapter class

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coba.get(position).getId()));
    holder.mDetView.setText(String.valueOf(coba.get(position).getSlug()));
    holder.mVerView.setText(String.valueOf(coba.get(position).getType()));
    holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),DetailBerita.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            System.out.println("Clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to notify the adapter. Retrofit won't do that for you.

Also, don't set `data = new ArrayList`. You need to instead `clear()` and `addAll()` if you want it to display in the adapter.

```
request.getPostDet().enqueue(new Callback<List<Coba>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Coba>> call, Response<List<Coba>> response) { 
        data.clear();
        try {
            List<Coba> responseBody = response.body();
            data.addAll(responseBody);
            Log.i("HASIL", "onResponse: "+data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: can u give the link of best  tutorial site for learning Retrofit  ?

Comment: it still doesnt show any data to the adapter. but when i check with for looping..its seems response its okay..

Comment: its working now..thanks..i add String.valueOf at my onbindview, then i use your solution by adding data.addAll(responseBody); ,without use data.clear;

Comment: If you don't use clear, you get duplicate data in the list on following calls to Retrofit